# Synchronizer and image_transport::Subscriber

Tags: message-filters, synchronization, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does message_filters::Synchronizer< POLICY > support image_transport::Subscriber?

As far as I've tried, it only supports message_filters::Subscriber, which is what I'm using now (following http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters).

Probably, using image_transport::Subscriber doesn't bring any advantage over message_filters::Subscriber!?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9705/synchronizer-and-image_transport::subscriber/) by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on ROS Answers with karma: 834 on 2011-04-12

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2011-04-15**:
Yes, it seems to be the way to do it. I'll follow the API (http://www.ros.org/doc/api/image_transport/html/classimage__transport_1_1SubscriberFilter.html), and post the solution if it works. Thanks for the hint!

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-04-15**:
I see. You want to synchronize two image topics. I never tried that so I cannot be really helpful here. Check http://answers.ros.org/question/226/how-to-synchronize-tfmessage-and-image-messages?comment=1455#comment-1455, especially Patrick's comment. Maybe it will help. Can you post your solution if you find one?

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2011-04-12**:
No. I'll give an example: I've two image_transport::Publisher in one node, so in another node I want to get those images synchronized. I've found that if you use image_transport::Subscriber, you cannot use message_filters::Synchronizer or any similar. Sorry if I've not explained well.

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-04-12**:
So, if I understand well, what you want to do is change the synchronization policy for a image_transport::Subscriber. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [Patrick's comment](http://answers.ros.org/question/226/how-to-synchronize-tfmessage-and-image-messages?comment=1455#comment-1455) we can use **image_transport::SubscriberFilter** (see the Code API). Indeed, it's encourage over **message_transport::Subscriber< sensor_msgs::Image >**. Thanks [Raphael](http://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/), for your help.

In the next code snippet we have a possible implementation. The macro **USE_IMAGE_TRANSPORT_SUBSCRIBER_FILTER** allows to switch between both approaches.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>

#define USE_IMAGE_TRANSPORT_SUBSCRIBER_FILTER 1

#if USE_IMAGE_TRANSPORT_SUBSCRIBER_FILTER
#  include <image_transport/subscriber_filter.h>
#else
#  include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>
#  include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#endif

class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass() :
    it_(nh_),
#if USE_IMAGE_TRANSPORT_SUBSCRIBER_FILTER
    orig_image_sub_( it_, "image/orig", 1 ),
    warp_image_sub_( it_, "image/warp", 1 ),
#else
    orig_image_sub_( nh_, "image/orig", 1 ),
    warp_image_sub_( nh_, "image/warp", 1 ),
#endif
    sync( MySyncPolicy( 10 ), orig_image_sub_, warp_image_sub_ )
  {
    sync.registerCallback( boost::bind( &MyClass::callback, this, _1, _2 ) );
  }

  void callback(
    const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& orig_msg,
    const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& warp_msg
  ){
    // your code here
  }

private:
  ros::NodeHandle nh_;
  image_transport::ImageTransport it_;

#if USE_IMAGE_TRANSPORT_SUBSCRIBER_FILTER
  typedef image_transport::SubscriberFilter ImageSubscriber;
#else
  typedef message_filters::Subscriber ImageSubscriber;
#endif

  ImageSubscriber orig_image_sub_;
  ImageSubscriber warp_image_sub_;

  typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime MySyncPolicy;

  message_filters::Synchronizer sync;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  ros::init( argc, argv, "my_node" );
  MyClass mc;
  
  while( ros::ok() ){
    ros::spin();
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that you can syncrhonize more messages (even of other type) by extending the **message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime< ... >** template class.

---

Originally posted by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) with karma: 834 on 2011-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 19

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2011-04-16**:
Please, mark as answered if you find it correct. Otherwise, let me know and I'll try to check and fix the problem. Thanks all!

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2012-02-28**:
This works. Note that, as I realized first-hand after hours of debugging, it is indeed compulsory to make the sync object a member object, i.e. not a temporary. Otherwise, there is no compilation time error or warning, but your callback never gets called. Even though there is no default constructor.

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2012-02-28**:
If you make it a temporary it gets destroyed when it leaves its context, so there's no longer a callback registered; same happens if you register callbacks for subscribers, or even other stuff like timers.

**Comment by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on 2017-06-13**:
You are missing CameraInfoConstPtr for image_transport right?

**Comment by [Enrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/244/enrique/) on 2019-03-11**:
@tanasis I'm using an image_transport::SubscriberFilter, so it's only for an image, not a camera. You also use a CameraSubscriber, in which case you get the Image and the CameraInfo messages synchronized.